# Decrement date month transition

Tags: c#, datetime, calculation, decrement

I have a function to decrement a date by one day each time is called.

```
private IEnumerable<DateTime> EachDay(DateTime from, DateTime thru)
{
    for (var day = thru.Date; day.Date >= from.Date; day = day.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)))//day.AddDays(-1))
    {
        yield return day;
    }
}
```

Seems to work fine until i arrive to the previous month. If someone have a solution ?

Comment: What happens when you arrive to the previous month? Can you show as example how do you use it?

Comment: Describe how it does not meet your expectations

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Also why not just `day = day.AddDays(-1)`

Answer (score 2):

I would be using something like this

```
private IEnumerable<DateTime> EachDay(DateTime from, DateTime thru)
{
    var days=(thru.Date - from.Date).Days;
    if (days <= 0)  yield return DateTime.MinValue;
    else for (var day = days; day >= 0; day-=1)
    yield return from.Date.AddDays(day);
}
```

test

```
var thru =new DateTime(day: 01,month:12, year:2021); 
var from= thru.AddDays(-10);
EachDay(from,thru).Dump();
```

result

```
    2021-12-01
    2021-11-30
    2021-11-29
    2021-11-28
    2021-11-27
    2021-11-26
    2021-11-25
    2021-11-24
    2021-11-23
    2021-11-22
    2021-11-21
```

Comment: thanks for the proposition but the the problem is not solved. For example, when i give 01/12/2021 the response is 01/00/2021 and not 30/11/2021.

Comment: @sviardot Pls, give 2 dates, from and to, when it is not working, another date must be invalid

Answer (score 1):

My other answer notwithstanding, you said in a comment on Serge's answer:

> when i give 01/12/2021 the response is 01/00/2021

I just wanted to point out that you may get this if you have a date of midnight on 01/12/2021 and you accidentally use a date format of `dd/mm/yyyy` when printing it out

`mm` is minutes, not months. `MM` is months.. If you're stringing your date using `mm` the 00 you're seeing is the minute from 00:00:00 time, not the month

All in your entire code might be fine ([it seems fine to me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8MSqVs)) and you're being misled by a typo in a ToString

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it. I store the value in a database and a piece of code induce an implicit conversion from native date format to french date format.
I force to use the native date format into all code and all is now fine.

Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

To some extent you're reinventing a wheel here. You can use Enumerable.Range to do your dates:

```
var f = // the date from eg DateTime.Now;
var t = // the date to eg DateTime.Now.AddDays(-45);

//this line of code generates the dates 
var d = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + (int)((f-t).TotalDays)).Select(x => f.AddDays(-x));
```

The dates in `d` have [no problem crossing a month boundary](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mTWrIA)